# extracting the list of user subscribed youtube channels for an authenticated user

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

How can I get the list of all the channels that the authenticated account is subscribed to on youtube in my android app. I also want the URL list of these channels so that user can get redirected to them on selecting the Url of a particular channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the YouTube data API to fetch information about the user's subscriptions. See here:
[Subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions)

In the "Methods" section of that documentation, you can see there is a [list method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list). This should return all the subscriptions.

You can use the `subscription.snippet.channelId` value to build the channel url; just concatenate it like this: `https://www.youtube.com/channel/<id>`

If you want info about the channel, you will probably have to use [Channels](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels).

Comment: thanx justin...just for the sake of confirming the feasibility of my project,i want to know whether the use of this API will return me the entire list of subscriptions alongwith their URL's and the info about any new uploads on these channels.Or do i need anything extra for that?